# smooth scroll after select radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, smoothing

I want user select a radio input

```
 <input id="package1" type="radio" name="package1" value="package1" onClick="document.getElementById('complate').scrollIntoView();" />
 <input id="package2" type="radio" name="package2" value="package2" onClick="document.getElementById('complate').scrollIntoView();" />
```

This event fast scroll to section but I need smooth scroll

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrollintoview animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102118/scrollintoview-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery snippet:

```
$('.packageBtn').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#complate').offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

And add the class of `packageBtn` to your radio buttons. E.G:

```
<input id="package1" class="packageBtn" type="radio" name="package1" value="package1"/>
```