# JavaScript Smooth Scrolling effect with scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, html, css, js-scrollintoview

Okay, I am attempting to get a single page (two divs), Primarily a splash screen, which when you click 'Enter site' it will scroll down smoothly to the 'main site', However it jumps to it, rather than smooth scrolling to the element.

How can I get it to scroll to that element smoothly without this jump effect?

Here is my a snippet:

```js
splash = document.getElementById('intro');
content = document.getElementById('content');

function enterSite() {
  content.scrollIntoView({
    behaviour: "smooth"
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#intro {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgsafe.org/51d0cf26df.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#splash {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50px 50px;
}

#splash-p {
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn {
  width: 35%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Main Content Page */

article {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro">
  <div id="splash">
    <p id="splash-p">Just a load of text repeated</p>
    <input
      type="image"
      src="Images/Button.png"
      class="btn"
      onclick="enterSite()"
    />
  </div>
</div>
<article id="content">Just a load of text repeated</article>
```

If you click the button it will jump to the next div, i need it to scroll smoothly, rather than jump to the next div. Using pure javascript, everywhere else i have looked seems to have plug ins or uses jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more comprehensive list of methods for smooth scrolling, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689657/9513184).

---

To scroll to a certain position in an exact amount of time, [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) can be put to use, calculating the appropriate current position each time. [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) can be used to a similar effect when `requestAnimationFrame` is not supported.

```js
/*
   @param pos: the y-position to scroll to (in pixels)
   @param time: the exact amount of time the scrolling will take (in milliseconds)
*/
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
```

Demo:

```js
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}

document.getElementById("toElement").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var elem = document.querySelector("div");
  scrollToSmoothly(elem.offsetTop);
});
document.getElementById("toTop").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  scrollToSmoothly(0, 700);
});
```

```html
<button id="toElement">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 1000px 0px; text-align: center;">Div element
  <button id="toTop">Scroll back to top</button>
</div>
```

For more complex cases, the [SmoothScroll.js library](https://github.com/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll) can be used, which handles smooth scrolling both vertically and horizontally, scrolling inside other container elements, different easing behaviors, scrolling relatively from the current position, and more.

```js
document.getElementById("toElement").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  smoothScroll({toElement: document.querySelector('div'), duration: 500});
});
document.getElementById("toTop").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  smoothScroll({yPos: 0, duration: 700});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll@1.2.0/src/smoothscroll.min.js" integrity="sha384-UdJHYJK9eDBy7vML0TvJGlCpvrJhCuOPGTc7tHbA+jHEgCgjWpPbmMvmd/2bzdXU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="toElement">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 1000px 0px; text-align: center;">Div element
  <button id="toTop">Scroll back to top</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can pass an options object to [`window.scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/scroll) which scrolls to a specific x and y position and [`window.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/scrollBy) which scrolls a certain amount from the current position:

```
// Scroll to specific values
// scrollTo is the same
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll certain amounts from current position 
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative value
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Demo:

```html
<button onClick="scrollToDiv()">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
<script>
function scrollToDiv(){
var elem = document.querySelector("div");
window.scroll({
      top: elem.offsetTop, 
      left: 0, 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
});
}
</script>
```

Modern browsers support the [`scroll-behavior` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior), which can be used to make scrolling in the document smooth (without the need for JavaScript).  Anchor tags can be used for this by giving the anchor tag a `href` of `#` plus the `id` of the element to scroll to). You can also set the `scroll-behavior` property for a specific container like a `div` to make its contents scroll smoothly.

Demo:

```css
html, body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<a href="#elem">Scroll To Element</a>
<div id="elem" style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
```

Comment: iota - this worked really well for me, thank you!

Comment: @ReenaVerma No problem.

Comment: @ReenaVerma In case you are interested, I have updated my answer with more methods.

Comment: this is really awesome, thank you for doing this.  I will have a good play around with these and understand them for the future :)

Comment: Re-marked this as best answer, due to original question preferring a non-jquery method as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Your `content.scrollIntoView({behaviour: "smooth"});` should work, however, I think 'behaviour' is spelt **behavior**.

I did develop a way of smooth scrolling with TypeScript, but you should be able to convert to JS quite easily:

[View stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102118/scrollintoview-animation/55572009#55572009)

Comment: Perfect for most browsers! However it looks as though parameters are not supported in IE11< (pffft! serves them right!) and Safari (yet...): https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Comment: Safari still not supported :| https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a straight jump, you should animate the scroll somehow.
With the help of jQuery is easy as that:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $([ELEMENT]).position().top }, 1000);
```

Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8501ckvn/

---

jQuery solves a lot of cross browser issues, but if you are looking for a **pure javascript** solution there are already many answers on Stackoverflow, i.e. look at [Smooth scroll anchor links WITHOUT jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733076/smooth-scroll-anchor-links-without-jquery).

Comment: I seen that question, but it is not a smooth scroll, I suppose i will just have to give up on javascript and use css for it.

Comment: Ok, but if I understood what you need I don't think you can control scroll only with CSS. Anyway it is a common pattern, you may also have a look at this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/smooth-scrolling-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: WHY is this the accepted answer??? He said JAVASCRIPT, not jquery. the eagerness with which everybody answers javascript questions with jQuery really kills me.

Comment: @Rup you're right and I feel guilty. But since the question was already answered I linked the VanillaJS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have JQuery as well.

You could make use of the following JQuery code to get a smooth scrolling effect

```
function enterSite(){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top
    }, 1500);
});
```

Let me know if it worked

Comment: I am looking for a vanilla answer i am afraid