# how to make javascript scrollIntoView smooth?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

In a react app, I have a method being called to bring a particular node into view as follows.

```
scrollToQuestionNode(id) {
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.scrollIntoView(false);
}
```

The scroll happens fine, but the scroll action is a little jerky. How can I make it smooth? I don't see any options which I can give to scrollIntoView for the same.

Comment: It's now supported by Chrome (from Chrome 61)

Answer (score 199):

This might help.

From MDN documentation of scrollIntoView
You can pass in option instead of boolean.

```
scrollIntoViewOptions Optional
A Boolean or an object with the following options:
{
  behavior: "auto"  | "instant" | "smooth",
  block:    "start" | "center" | "end" | "nearest",
  inline:    "start" | "center" | "end" | "nearest",
}
```

So you can simply pass parameter like this.

```
scrollToQuestionNode(id) {
  const element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end',  behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Thanks lavish, but I already tried it. As you can see in the link you mentioned, scrollIntoViewOptions is not supported in chrome ( I find it strange, but thats the reality)

Comment: That is strange. Are you using jquery? If you are then this is easy otherwise might have to take another approach.

Comment: It's now supported by Chrome (from Chrome 61)

Comment: it won't work in safari and IE browsers as per MDN documentation

Comment: That is correct, IE, edge etc does not support smooth behaviour unfortunately.

Comment: There is a polyfill for non supporting browsers: [link](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll)

Comment: it seems like the support is in all browsers by now

Comment: is it possible to use easing? say `{ easing: 'easeInElastic' }` or something like that. Or am I thinking ways to simply>

Answer (score 25):

For multibrowser support use the smooth-scroll-polyfill from [here](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll)

For easy implementation use a `wrapper` like this around the `polyfill` so the `.js` `polyfill` method would be inizialized after loading:

https://codepen.io/diyifang/embed/MmQyoQ?height=265&theme-id=0&default-tab=js,result&embed-version=2

Now this should work cross browser:

```
document.querySelector('.foo').scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this CSS on the div with the scrollbar:

```
.element-with-the-scrollbar {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

This gives smooth scrolling even when you just do:

```
elementWithTheScrollbar.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: This is the only right solution, because scrollIntoView does not support both false and a scrollIntoViewOptions as args: only one of these can be used at a time.

Answer (score 2):

What saved me was applying CSS smooth behavior with JS:

```
document.documentElement.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
```

Just before calling the function

```
document.getElementById("id-name").scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help too but I'm working on a Vue app I had a similar need, since removing one of the last elements on a page list left blank space on the bottom (I needed to remove the blank space by scrolling down). So, the removing happens through a button function. After all's done and when it's needed, I'm targeting the last div in the list and stating

```
div.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"})
```