# Why is [scrollIntoView()] not scrolling smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have been trying out some things to get more used to web dev.

I found a cool thing; scrollIntoView(), where it it is supposed to scroll smoothly to the next id-tag.

```
<button type="button"
          onclick="document.querySelector('#projects-overview')
          .scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});">
    Click Me!
  </button>
```

And this should smoothly scroll to id: projects overview in dashboard.component.html:

```
<div class="grid-container">
 <h1 id="projects-overview" class="mat-h1">Projects</h1>
```

Now this works, in a sence that it "goes" to the id, but it does not do this smoothly?

Any help/comments are really appreciated.

*i made this in an Angular project, and the latest edition of Chrome*

SNIPPET can be found here: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kgn5zo1L/)

Comment: [Please state the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: (Reopened it because it is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503599/how-to-make-javascript-scrollintoview-smooth))

Comment: Please provide more information and ideally a [mcve].

Comment: @str certainly a [dupe of something](https://www.google.com/search?q=scrollintoview+behavior+smooth+angular+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: "Of something" probably, but not of the question it was closed for ;)

Comment: Very likely the solution was there  - browser support issue

Comment: Maybe. Voting to close because we need debugging details.

Comment: @mplungjan

Thanks for the responses, i know it looks like a duplicate, but i have read through a lot of docs on Angular, CSS Tricks and Stackoverflow and for some reason nothing seems to help.

For browser suppot, i am using the latest Google Chrome.

Can you tell me what more details you would like?

Comment: @str I have made a snippet that does the same as my code, it jumps to te div, instead of smooth scrolling

Comment: Your fiddle works just fine, scrolling smoothly, so not much more to do here.

Comment: @Ason oops that is not my fiddle, sorry will edit it!

Comment: Well, that fiddle works just fine too.

Comment: @Ason weird, since on chrome with me it doesn't work at all? Any tips on how to fix that, or check what is wrong?

Comment: No, as we need something that doesn't work. And FYI, I use Chrome and it works.

Comment: @Diorcula The code works as it should. Do happen to have an OS or browser preference to reduce motion? That might be the problem, though on macOS 10.14 Chrome does not follow the corresponding OS setting. But it might do so on another OS. Does it work for you using another browser?

Comment: @str Hm i will check, for now just thanks and i will close the question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is a option in Chrome to disable/enable smooth scrolling options (which i had turned to default so it didn't work.)

To enable smooth scrolling in Chrome go to: chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling

it all works smoothly now.

furthermore i found that there are multiple ways to scroll smoothly:

#1: in the CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

#2: in the HTML itself

```
  <button type="button"
      onclick="document.querySelector('#projects-overview')
      .scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});">
Click Me!
  </button>
```

Comment: This is poor practice. You shouldn't use JavaScript logic like this in the DOM.

Comment: hi @markmead i get your point, but what do you suppose for an answer then?

Comment: What I posted as the answer. You need to be using unobtrusive JavaScript.

Comment: @markmead okidoki, when i have some time to spare i will try to write it with unobtrusive JavaScript!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, extracting the JavaScript out of the HTML fixes the issue.

The error I get in the console when running your code is `Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null`

```js
const buttonEl = document.querySelector("#clickMe");
const scrollEl = document.querySelector("#scollToMe");

buttonEl.addEventListener("click", function () {
  scrollEl.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  })
})
```

```css
.scroll-el {
  margin-top: 200vh;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id='clickMe' type='button'>Click me</button>
<div class='scroll-el' id='scollToMe'></div>
```

Comment: Why do you make use of the eventlistener if i may ask?

Comment: @Diorcula Read this regarding why to use `addEventListener`: https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript