# Scroll to element on click in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to be able to scroll to a target when a button is pressed. I was thinking something like this.

```
<button (click)="scroll(#target)">Button</button>
```

And in my `component.ts` a method like.

```
scroll(element) {
    window.scrollTo(element.yPosition)
}
```

I know that the code above is not valid but just to show what I was thinking. I've just started to learn Angular 4 with no previous experience of Angular. I've been searching around for something like this but all the examples are in AngularJs which differs a lot to Angular 4

Comment: Your syntax does not have problems but you need to define what is #target.

Comment: So this should work? When I use a arbitrary number and call window.scrollTo(500) in my function nothing happens. I was thinking that element would be a HTMLElement

Comment: Right, however, what is #target, Angular will not resolve it? You can test scroll() with no parameter first.

Comment: Yeah I tried (click)="scroll()" in my button and window.scrollTo(0, 500) in the component but nothing happens

Comment: Check this: https://plnkr.co/edit/A0WhJVx8CP1Ai78dbvPQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for that! I've been trying to do that but it just won't scroll. I print to console in my scroll function to see if it ever got there and it does. It seems that the window.scrollTo(0, 500) doesn't get executed

Comment: But when I do window.scrollTo(0, 500) in the constructor with a 500ms delay it works

Comment: Hmm, weird. If you can recreate it in plunker, we can help to check it.

Comment: I just figured it out. I wasn't using a button as I wrote in the description, I was using a a-tag. Sorry for the confusing you and thanks for the help! It works now

Comment: Little late to this party, but I've written a plugin for Angular 4+ that does just this. It covers other issues you may bump into, like Server-Side Rendering. You can also animate to scrolling to your likings. Full disclosure, I'm the author. [NPM: @nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to) [GitHub: @nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to](https://github.com/nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to) Hope this helps you out!

Comment: The "smooth" option has very instable support, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview. This is why I went with some more graceful decision. I agree the code might look a lot, but it serves most of the browsers.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I'm not familiar with the approach you describe, but it sounds interesting. Please feel free to suggest any improvements or additions to the `ngx-scroll-to` package, your knowledge and input is always very welcome. If you wanna talk more about the subject I'd suggest you file issues on the GitHub repo. Thanks for your input thus far!

Comment: This is super good. Ended up adding because I was loading a child component  setTimeout(() => {
        this.scrollToService.scrollTo(config);
      }, 300);

Comment: Which JS framework is this? and also, can we use it with Angular v8?

Comment: Cool - This actually works with Angular V8?

Answer (score 252):

You could do it like this:

```
<button (click)="scroll(target)">Scroll To Div</button>
<div #target>Your target</div>
```

and then in your component:

```
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

**Edit:** I see comments stating that this no longer works due to the element being undefined. I created a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-local-variable) in Angular 7 and it still works. Can someone please provide an example where it does not work?

Comment: For some reason running that exact code does nothing for me. Even a hardcoded window.scrollTo(0, 500) does nothing

Comment: Can you confirm that your `scroll` method in your component is executing? Add a `console.log(el)` and open your browser's Developer Tools to see if you are getting the correct element. Also, check the console for errors.

Comment: I had to use el.scrollIntoView(true)

Comment: @N15M0_jk Yep, there's also an object you can pass in with other options, depending on what you need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: @FrankModica yea that's where I read up on the parameters :) really helped me out, never knew about scrollIntoView before seeing your post actually

Comment: What does adding "#target" to the div do?

Comment: @Anthony It allows you to reference the element that you want to pass to the `scroll` function on the component. Notice that the click event calls `scroll(target)`. If you wanted to get access to the element from inside the component without having to pass the element in, you could use `@ViewChild`.

Comment: Following link will be a right solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616843/how-to-call-scrollintoview-on-an-element-in-angular-2

Comment: @blueprintchris I posted a link to StackBlitz where it works in Angular 7. I know this was a while ago, but if you remember a situation where it did not work please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It works fine with me now. But before i made a silly mistake and used `id="target"` instead of `#target` and it gave me "el is undefined error"!

Comment: I have seen that some people using this in Safari and some special browser and it doesn't work.

Comment: I believe the undefined error happens if the element with the `#target` is inside an `*ngIf`, but it should work if you use the `@ViewChild` method in the link from @abbastec

Comment: the correct answer, also about the center option from the above answer.
{ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' }

Comment: simple and neat. Works for me in Angular 10

Comment: The `undefined` error is probably happening when `scroll(target)` is used and the target is not defined. If the id is called target then the target in the scroll call needs to be in quotes e.g. `scroll('target')`.

Comment: It works just if the #id is hardcoded. but if you want to generate the id when the page is rendered (like ngFor) it's not working.

Comment: Works for me "@angular/core": "^13.0.0".

Answer (score 131):

In Angular 13 works perfect

HTML

```html
<button (click)="scroll(target)">Click to scroll</button>
<div #target>Your target</div>
```

In component

```js
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Comment: bonus for {behavior: 'smooth'}

Comment: It's working for me.. special thanks for {behavior: 'smooth'}

Comment: This will not work if ```#target``` is defined after the button, which is relevant if you have a floating header for example...

Comment: Awesome, works for me too and appreciate the bonus of smooth scrolling

Comment: Confirmed working as expected in Angular 12.  Well done!

Comment: This works perfectly. Bonus: el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })  --- worked better for me; To have a smooth transition & not scroll the whole page in the case of a side-navigation. Ref->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039885/scrollintoview-causing-the-whole-page-to-move

Answer (score 87):

Here is how I did it using Angular 4.

Template

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
  <h2>Categories</h2>
  <div class="cat-list-body">
    <div class="cat-item" *ngFor="let cat of web.menu | async">
      <label (click)="scroll('cat-'+cat.category_id)">{{cat.category_name}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

add this function to the Component.

```
scroll(id) {
  console.log(`scrolling to ${id}`);
  let el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: You haven't set elementRefs or HTML ids in your template. Where exactly is the 'cat-'+cat.category_id element that you are scrolling to?

Comment: This is a better answer. You can put the scroll to another component.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Working for Angular 9.

Comment: Working in Angular 11

Comment: Hey @Keegan, in this case you may assume that `web.menu` is an array of categories.

Comment: This is better answer because it's dynamic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36180398/1266873  in case you want it animated.

Answer (score 58):

There is actually a pure javascript way to accomplish this without using `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` or jQuery.

In short, find the element in the scrollView that you want to scroll to, and use `scrollIntoView`.

`el.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});`

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Z2CsiJ6WYC712Q9pUtc).

Comment: 2 ways that this answer is different:
1. This is animated smooth scrolling, not a jump.
2. This answer does not scroll a window, but moves a scrollview within a window.  For example, if you have a horizontal scrollview within the window.  Check the plunkr for an example.

Comment: scrollIntoView's scrollIntoViewOptions (the object as argument) is only compatible with Firefox right now.

Comment: Works fine for Chrome and Firefox, but not for Safari.

Comment: This worked for me in Angular 9

Answer (score 29):

Another way to do it in Angular:

Markup:

```
<textarea #inputMessage></textarea>
```

Add `ViewChild()` property:

```
@ViewChild('inputMessage')
inputMessageRef: ElementRef;
```

Scroll anywhere you want inside of the component using `scrollIntoView()` function:

```
this.inputMessageRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 26):

Jon has the right answer and this works in my angular 5 and 6 projects.

If I wanted to click to smoothly scroll from navbar to footer:

```
<button (click)="scrollTo('.footer')">ScrolltoFooter</button>
<footer class="footer">some code</footer>

scrollTo(className: string):void {
   const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);
   const element = elementList[0] as HTMLElement;
   element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

Because I wanted to scroll back to the header from the footer, I created a service that this function is located in and injected it into the navbar and footer components and passed in 'header' or 'footer' where needed. just remember to actually give the component declarations the class names used:

```
<app-footer class="footer"></app-footer>
```

Comment: In Angular 14 it works without the dot 
(click)="scrollTo('footer')"

Answer (score 21):

You can scroll to any element ref on your view by using the code block below.
Note that the target **(elementref id**) could be on any valid html tag.

On the view(html file)

```
<div id="target"> </div>
<button (click)="scroll()">Button</button>
```

on the `.ts` file,

```
scroll() {
   document.querySelector('#target').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In Angular you can use `ViewChild` and `ElementRef`:
give your HTML element a ref

```
<div #myDiv></div>
```

and inside your component:

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('myDiv') myDivRef: ElementRef;
```

you can use `this.myDivRef.nativeElement` to get to your element

Comment: This is a good solution but problem is that it only works when i reload the tab but not with routerLink. Any solution for this problem guys ?

Comment: how I can use a `class` with this?

Comment: @Ahsan you might want to try ngAfterViewInit or ngAfterViewChecked.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve that by using the reference to an angular DOM element as follows:

Here is the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-angular-scroll-to-element-example)

the component template:

```html
<div class="other-content">
      Other content
      <button (click)="element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' })">
        Click to scroll
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="content" #element>
      Some text to scroll
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the scroll goes too far

Get correct y coordinate and use window.scrollTo({top: y, behavior: 'smooth'})

Set different y coordinate if using multiple elements

Html file

```
<div class="sub-menu">
  <button (click)="scroll('#target1', -565)">Target One</button>
  <button (click)="scroll('#target2', -490)">Target Two</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="target1">Target One</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="target2">Target Two</div>
</div>
```

ts file

```
  scroll(elem: string, offset: number) {
    const yOffset = offset;
    const element = document.querySelector(elem)!;
    const y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset + yOffset;

    window.scrollTo({ top: y, behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I tried the simplest solution, which was the use of DOM commands like `Element.scrollIntoView()`, or

```
document.getElementById("<yourTarget>").scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth",
  block: "start",
  inline: "nearest"
});
```

(Remember to add `id="<yourtarget>"` where you want to scroll)
It worked on development, and it was quite easy, but after deploying to production environment I noticed that the scroll was not working!

So, I tried another way, using Angular's ViewportScroller.
In order to do that, you have to inject ViewportScroller at Component's constructor, like `constructor(private scroller: ViewportScroller)` and just call `this.scroller.scrollToAnchor("<yourTarget>");`. Again, no big deal, and again it was NOT WORKING on production environment.

The third way to do it, is to use Router to provide navigation to the anchor I wanted. Similarly to the last option, inject Router to constructor, like

`constructor(private router: Router)`, and use the command:
`this.router.navigate([], { fragment: "<yourTarget>" });`
Finally it DID WORK on production environment! I don't know for sure why the previous methods failed, I read some sources that says Angular Material blocks scrolling, but I'm not sure.

In order to present the different options there's a Stackblitz as an example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/scrolling-types

There you can click on tree buttons, each one using a different method to scroll down to some anchor.

Answer (score 0):

For me the top answer moved my entire component causing areas of the page to be blocked off. I fixed it by adding some additional properties

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 15:
I had an issue where scrolling was not working because I was using *ngIf directive with a variable that was updated at same time when I was triggering scroll.
In one change detection, it did not update the variable, and that part of HTML did not exist, so I used setTimeout, to do the scrolling in another change detection.

```
<div  (click)="someVariable = true; scroll()">
<div *ngIf="someVariable" #menuHamburgerDiv>



@ViewChild('menuHamburgerDiv') menuDiv: ElementRef;
 
 scroll() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.menuDiv.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }, 0);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    goToDIV() {
    
        document.getElementById('targetBlue').scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          block: 'start',
          inline: 'nearest',
        });
      }

 <div id="targetBlue" >
    <h2 class=""><b>Blocage temporaire</b></h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post. Also, do not dump the same answers on multiple questions please. Instead. [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) them for closure as a [duplicate](/help/duplicates).

Answer (score -2):

I need to do this trick, maybe because I use a custom HTML element. If I do not do this,
`target` in `onItemAmounterClick` won't have the `scrollIntoView` method

.html

```
<div *ngFor"...">
      <my-component #target (click)="clicked(target)"></my-component>
</div>
```

.ts

```
onItemAmounterClick(target){
  target.__ngContext__[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Answer (score -21):

You can do this by using jquery :

ts code :

```
    scrollTOElement = (element, offsetParam?, speedParam?) => {
    const toElement = $(element);
    const focusElement = $(element);
    const offset = offsetParam * 1 || 200;
    const speed = speedParam * 1 || 500;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: toElement.offset().top + offset
    }, speed);
    if (focusElement) {
      $(focusElement).focus();
    }
  }
```

html code :

```
<button (click)="scrollTOElement('#elementTo',500,3000)">Scroll</button>
```

Apply this on elements you want to scroll :

```
<div id="elementTo">some content</div>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scroll-to-element-7v7mca) is a stackblitz sample.

Comment: Except this op is asking for TypeScript solutions not work arounds with an obsolete framework (down voted)

Comment: You’ve missed my point, your answer uses jQuery (might I add in the most inefficient way) rather than simply using ES*.  Your constants don’t declare their type neither.  It’s just a bad example with bad logic using jQuery which is not what was asked.