# How to call scrollIntoView on an element in angular 2+

Tags: angular

I want to call [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on a HTML element in a component.

In angular.js 1 I can do something like this in the controller:

```
var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
```

How can I do the same thing in angular 2+ ?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

First add a template reference variable in the element (the `#myElem`):

```
<p #myElem>Scroll to here!</p>
```

Then create a property in the component with attribute `ViewChild`, and call `.nativeElement.scrollIntoView` on it:

```
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild("myElem") MyProp: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.MyProp.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the recommendation (or counter-recommendation) with regards to nativeElement specifically?

Comment: Every time this comes up, it's "Don't use nativeElement," and no discussion of the "recommended way."

Comment: The current official recommendation is to use Renderer2 to wrap the nativeElement
private el: ElementRef,
private renderer: Renderer2
--
this.el.nativeElement.style.color = 'blue';  //not recommended
this.renderer2.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'color', 'blue');  //recommended

Comment: But I don't see renderer2 support of `scrollIntoView`

Comment: @Drenai how do you define recommended way? its simple dom manipulation. Angular did provide Renderer2 but certain operations like scroll are not supported. also you are doing same thing using document.queryselector how's that recommended then.. nativeElement is selecting same thing

Comment: scrollIntoView add SetTimeout worked for me

Comment: scrollIntoView works for me but in my case, I should remove { behavior: "smooth", block: "start" } to work.

Answer (score 19):

You could intercept the NavigationEnd event

```
    private scrollToSectionHook() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            const tree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
            if (tree.fragment) {
                const element = document.querySelector('#' + tree.fragment);
                if (element) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});
                    }, 500 );
                }
            }
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Should be the accepted answer. Plug and play, just inject router and import navigationEvent! Wow, thank you.

Comment: This is a really great answer!  SetTimeout for the element.scrollIntoView did help!

Comment: I used this approach but didn't work. By the way, I use SetTimeout and it works. (notice: duration of SetTimeout should be more than 400ms. Below 400ms didn't work for me)

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve the same animated scroll to the element in Angular 2+, simply pass the element on click, like so:

```
<button mat-fab (click)="scroll(target)">
    <i class="material-icons">
      arrow_drop_down
    </i>
 </button>
<div #target></div>

public scroll(element: any) {
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
```

Comment: your solution did'nt worked as is for me, have assigned `element=document.querySelector('#target'); element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });` than it works, :)

Comment: The above mentioned solution works on click, where you need to pass the element in to the method as a parameter, that's why you wouldn't need to use "element=document.querySelector('#target')"

Comment: I take my words back, It works, I was passing name of element instead of element, so it made me to use querySelector

Comment: "start" that's the default value for block, no sense to add it as it is.

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 simple ways to use **scrollIntoView**

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-smooth?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**The first way**

In app.component.html file:

```
<button (click)="scrollPoint1(point_1)">
  Click to scroll - Point 1
</button>

<div>
  <h3 #point_1>Point 1</h3>
</div>
```

In app.component.ts file:

```
scrollPoint1(el: HTMLElement) {
  // el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

**Second way**

In app.component.html file:

```
<button click)="scrollPoint2()">
  Click to scroll - Point 2
</button>

<div>
  <h3 id="point_2">Point 2</h3>
</div>
```

In app.component.ts file:

```
scrollPoint2() {
  // document.getElementById("point_2").scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  document.getElementById('point_2').scrollIntoView();
}
```

**Third way**

In app.component.html file:

```
<button (click)="scrollPoint3()">
  Click to scroll - Point 3
</button>

<div>
  <h3 #point_3>Point 3</h3>
</div>
```

In app.component.ts file:

```
@ViewChild('point_3') private my_point_3: ElementRef;
scrollPoint3() {
  // this.my_point_3.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  this.my_point_3.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

it's already been answered a while ago but the cleanest way to achieve it is doing that on directive which also provides reusability.

here's an example for directive which will scroll an element into view, triggered by mouse click:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ScrollIntoViewOnClick]'
})
export class ScrollIntoViewOnClickDirective {

    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
    scrollIntoView() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this._elementRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
        }, 200)
    }
}
```

then all you got to do is add that directive on the relevant element to trigger that functionality when it is clicked.

hope it helps anyone.

Comment: If you can click the element, doesn't that mean it is already in view?

Answer (score 4):

We had some issues with our hybrid where none of this worked. If you just want a simple solution you could also opt for adding a timeout to break out of Angular.

E.g.

`<a (click)="onClick('foo')">`

```
onClick(id: string): void {
    const el: HTMLElement|null = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el) {
      setTimeout(() =>
        el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'}), 0);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Capacitor to wrap an Angular app. scrollIntoView wasn't working but wrapping it in a **setTimeout()** function to make it a synchronous call worked. I don't know why. I've had a similar issue when trying to open modals/dialogs in the constructor. .

Answer (score 1):

I could only get it working by wrapping in `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout`

```
@ViewChild('someElement') someElementRef: ElementRef;

...

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  this.someElementRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
});
```

```
<div #someElement>test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take (also, this works on Angular 15). Add an empty section to your template:

```
<section #resultsStart></section>
```

Refer to it in the TS file:

```
@ViewChild('resultsStart', { read: ElementRef }) resultsStart: ElementRef;
```

And after that when some event happens (for example, page change):

```
    this.resultsStart.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'end',
    });
```

For more information on the options, you can check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tag doesn't work due to rendering on real time for scroll

- scrollIntoView() - *Not working*
- scrollIntoViewIfNeeded() - *Not working*

Use native element **WINDOW.SCROLL** and **SET TIME OUT**

Find the ID present within DOM, then map it to array and grab the URL's HASH, match with the ID. If true then use window scroll event using offset.

Hope it helps!!!

***Below is the example of using nativeElement***

**Article-component.ts**

```
import { DOCUMENT, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import {  Component,  ElementRef,  Inject,  OnDestroy,  OnInit,  PLATFORM_ID,  QueryList,  ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-details',
  templateUrl: './article-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-details.component.scss'],
})
export class ArticleDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChildren('section') articleSections!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  data$!: Observable<Insight | null>;

  private isBrowser: boolean = false;
  siteURL: any;
  hashID : any;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private dom: Document,
  ) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.siteURL = new URL(this.dom.URL);
    this.isAnchor();
  }

//Scrolling to Anchor ID
  isAnchor() {
    this.hashID = this.siteURL.hash;
    this.hashID = this.hashID.replace('#', '');

    setTimeout(() => {
      const foundID = Array.from(this.articleSections).find(
        (el) => el.nativeElement.id === this.hashID
      );
      if (!foundID) return;
      if (this.isBrowser) {
        window.scroll({
          top: foundID?.nativeElement.offsetTop - 200,
          left: 0,
          behavior: 'smooth',
        });
      }
    }, 400);
  }
}
```

**Article-component.html**

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let slice of vm.data.slices.items">    
         <ng-container [ngSwitch]="slice.__typename">
            <section #section [attr.id]="slice.quickLink?.slug">
              <app-slice-wysiwyg
                *ngSwitchCase="articleDetailsSlice.Wysiwyg"
                [slice]="$any(slice)"
              ></app-slice-wysiwyg>
            </section>
          </ng-container>
   </ng-container>
```