# Accessing global objects with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I want to know the best way to access global objects and emit some events on these objects in Angular App things like ( window, local storage, document or any other purpose)

and is it right to call it like a JS object or should I stick to the Angular way of doing so?

and if I'm not allowed to manipulate DOM with any other library like jQuery in an angular app?

Comment: The angular way would suit, add it to a global constants and then access the details by importing them in your component TS files.

Comment: Don't use Jquery and Angular together. Angular already solves the problem of DOM manipulation for you

Comment: okay so how to import these objects ,, lets say I wanna scroll to top of the document how do I access document to perform such thing

Comment: using viewchild or passing local element will be a better practice than window.scrollTo(x, y). Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616843/how-to-call-scrollintoview-on-an-element-in-angular-2

Comment: okay but what if I do not want to scroll to an element ,, what if i wanted to access document object or window object itself not something in the view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common way is to use services to keep track of objects around the app. Wherever you want to access some data, you simply just inject that corresponding service. You can read more about services here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

When it comes to DOM manipulation, Angular have their own functionalities for communicating with the DOM. For example you can manipulate the DOM using the built in Renderer2. You can also get access to the nativeElement of some element reference. It's not recommended to manually update the DOM with Vanilla JS or jQuery.

Renderer2: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

ElementRef: https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Comment: okay so which is which ,, which is there to get me an access to lets say all window methods or any other API ?

Comment: If you are 100% sure that the application runs in a browser (not rendered server side), you can of course use the window API's as you normally would. However, if you need some DOM properties an a specific element (div/span/table or whatever) you should use ElementRef, and from there get access to the nativeElement. Read more about accessing window here: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/

Answer (score 2):

I would advice the following:

Don't access the document object for DOM manipulation or use JQuery. Angular itself provides all the methods required in order to manipulate the DOM. Using Angular and JQuery in conjunction would be an antipattern (IMO).

Here are some tools in Angular which allow you to manipulate the DOM:

1. [Template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), For dynamicallly outputting html text
2. [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass), For dynamicallly adding strings
3. [*NgIf directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf), for conditionally showing certain DOM elements
4. [Renderer2](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-explore-the-renderer-service-e43ef673b26c), for Doing all sorts of DOM manipulation.

Things like localstorage and sessionstorage you can directly access from your angular application.

For holding your global data I would advice you to use services which allows components to easily share data between each other.

Of course you could in theory add jQuery or another library for DOM manipulation but this defeats the whole purpose of using Angular in the first place. Since we want to use Angular for creating SPA's application in a relatively easy manner.

Comment: okay so which is which ,, which is there to get me an access to lets say all window methods or any other API ?

Comment: Some of them like AJAX request XMLHttpRequest are handled by Angular but most of them you can use freely yes. The rule of thumb is, check if there is an Angualar way of doing things, If there is use that way since it is often easier or more performant.