# Angular 2 scrollIntoView Not Scrolling

Tags: angular

I have a DIV with the id of `footerWrapperTop` in my HTML.

I have the following TypeScript in my component:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    try {
      this.sFragment = 'footerWrapperTop';
      const nativeElement = document.querySelector('#' + this.sFragment);
      nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
    } catch (e) { }   }
```

However the page does not scroll down to the footer at runtime. What am I doing wrong?

If I `console.dir(nativeElement);` it shows the DIV in the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **Angular's Renderer**

> Supply a **Second Argument for selectRootElement** as per [Angular's Official Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#selectrootelement) as it is **used to preserve your content**
>
> **Syntax:** `selectRootElement(selectorOrNode: any, preserveContent?: boolean): any`

Had created a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-scrollintoview) for your reference

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';


@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  sFragment: string;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.sFragment = 'footerWrapperTop';

      const element = this.renderer.selectRootElement(`#${this.sFragment}`, true); // true to indicate that you will preserve the content

      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });   // for smooth scrolling

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this question: [How to call scrollIntoView on an element in angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616843/how-to-call-scrollintoview-on-an-element-in-angular-2)

First add a template reference variable in the element (the #footerWrapperTop):

```
<div #footerWrapperTop></div>
```

in component.ts:

```
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild("footerWrapperTop") MyProp: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.MyProp.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
  }
}
```

However, when router changes, there is a bug in angular 5 and lower version. Angular 6 has fixed the problem. check this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7791

Comment: it's safer to use Renderer2

Answer (score 0):

User Renderer2 from angular

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div #targetDiv style="height: 1000px;"></div>
    <button (click)="scrollToDiv()">Scroll to Div</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('targetDiv') targetDiv: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  scrollToDiv() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(window, 'scrollTo', {
      top: this.targetDiv.nativeElement.offsetTop,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }
}
```