# Result of "document.getElementById()" is Null

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'd like to scroll to a particular element on an event (onEmitKennlinie()), but it doesnt't work.
Why is the result (var element) of "document.getElementById()" Null?

Here is my code:

```js
onEmitKennlinie(isKennlinie: boolean) {
  if(isKennlinie){ 
    var element = document.getElementById('Kennlinien_Anfang') as HTMLElement;
    console.log("ELEMENT ", element);
    if(element) {
      element.scrollIntoView(); // scroll to a particular element
    }
  }
}
```

This is my HTML:

```html
<div id="Kennlinien_Anfang">
   <app-schrauberdaten-kennliniengrafik
      (Report)="onReportKennlinien($event)">
   </app-schrauberdaten-kennliniengrafik>
</div>
```

Comment: This code works for me, when in the lifecycle of the component are you calling this method?

Comment: This might also help, a more "Angular-ly" solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616843/how-to-call-scrollintoview-on-an-element-in-angular-2