# I want to scroll to the top of the page as my list contains a long list of data, how do i do this?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been going through articles that covers the same question however most of them are done using javascript. I want to accomplish this in Angular 4 and ironic 3.

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to element on click in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945548/scroll-to-element-on-click-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ionic 2 and higher use the `scrollToTop()` method on the content class.

page.html

```
<ion-content>
  Add your content here!
</ion-content>
```

page.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop(400);
  }
}
```

Or you can call scrollTop() whenever you want. 
Note: 400 is duration in milliseconds, it is optional and you can use this as well

> this.content.scrollToTop();

in this case scrollToTop() will set the default value of 300.