# Scroll to the center of a DIV element - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to scroll to the Y and X center of my element when a certain function is fired.
My HTML look like this (i want to scroll to the middle of #viewport):

```
 </div>
      <div #viewport class="document-view-port">
          <div #viewBox></div>
 </div>
```

Inside my TS i am importing the elements like this(here i try to find the y center):

```
  @ViewChild('viewBox') viewBox: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('viewport') viewport: ElementRef;
```

The last methods that i try to extract this center point to scroll is:

```
  zoomIn() {
    const elementRect = this.viewport.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const absoluteElementTop = elementRect.top + window.pageYOffset;
    const middle = absoluteElementTop - (elementRect.height / 2);  
    this.viewport.nativeElement.scrollTo(0, middle)
  }
```

I just can't make it happen, any help would be appreciated

[edit]

The method scrollIntoView() don't do anything in my code. I want to find those cordinates and scroll without using any predefined function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to element on click in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945548/scroll-to-element-on-click-in-angular-4)

Comment: @JamieRees. It doesn't help. The `scrollIntoView()` simply don't do anything in my case.

Comment: you should use `window.scrollTo(0, middle);` for scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You should use `window.scrollTo(x, y)` for achieving the scroll:

```
zoomIn() {
    const elementRect = this.viewport.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const absoluteElementTop = elementRect.top + window.pageYOffset;
    const middle = absoluteElementTop - (elementRect.height / 2);  
    window.scrollTo(0, middle); // have a window object reference in your component
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried the code and its not doing anything `middle = -225`

Comment: @Igor.ro what did you expect with -225? That is never going to work. Try debugging why its a negative value. The value must be positive to work.