# How to come back to a component from another without reloading the component in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component in angular containing multiple child component. It also has logic for hiding and showing component on the basis of condition within that component.
eg.

```
 <div *ngFor="let data of dataSource; let i=index">
 <child-component [dataOne]="data.one"></child-component>
 <mat-divider></mat-divider>
 <second-child-component [dataTwo]="data.two"></second-child-component>
 </div>
```

I want to implement the functionality of navigating back without the page refresh and back to position where it previously was.

I did it by injecting the `Location` in constructor and using the `back()` method of it. However it reinitialize the previous component.

How do I do that? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the location.back() only applies to routes, not what you are trying to do. What you need instead is a way to store the history of the conditions that shows/hides the components.

Answer (score 0):

If by returing the same place you mean scroll there, you can use something like this:

```js
  scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
  }
```

and see more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43945776/1037613)

If you don't want to render the data again, you can try to hide this with CSS
Or

moving out of the screen with `position: absolute` and `bottom:-10000`

or

`display: None`