# angular 2+, slide to the specified element by hash(#) url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

Html can jump to the specified position through hash(#) url, for example:

index.html:

```
<div id='loc_a'>
 loc_a
</div>
<div id='loc_b'>
 loc_b
</div>
<div id='loc_c'>
 loc_c
</div>
```

If you want to swipe directly to position `loc_c`, you can use the following URL:`http:\\127.0.0.1:4200\index.html#loc_c`

But angular router doesn't recognize hash URL, whether the specified element is in the main component or a child route.

Router example:

```
{
  path: '', component: mainComponent,
  children: [
    {path: '', component: childrenComponent},
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can refer this link for your question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945548/scroll-to-element-on-click-in-angular-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945548/scroll-to-element-on-click-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

```
const ele = document.getElementById(elementId);
if (ele) {
  window.scrollTo(ele.offsetLeft, ele.offsetTop);
}
```