# Vue3 - scrollIntoView in watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to type in the input, and if the value of input matches "1" it will scroll to `.here`, but it isn't working,

I tried creating a button and adding a handle-click function. It worked.

Please help me.

```js
<template>
  <button @click="scrollToView">Click to Here</button>
  <input type="text" v-model="searchAddress" />
  <span v-if="matchAddress">OK</span>
  <span class="here" ref="el">Here</span>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed, watch, nextTick } from "vue";
const searchAddress = ref(null);
const el = ref(null);
const matchAddress = computed(() => {
  return searchAddress.value == 1;
});
function scrollToView() {
  el.value.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" });
  el.value.focus({ preventScroll: true });
}
watch(matchAddress, async (val) => {
  console.log(val);
  if (val) {
    await nextTick();
    scrollToView();
  }
});
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-composition-api-demo-forked-o6j7jm?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: What do you mean by it "isn't working"? Please elaborate.

Comment: function `scrollToView` not working. when i type `1` in the input

Comment: It seems to work in your demo, I type in 1 I go to "here"

Comment: it should work with `v-model.lazy`, but you have to blur (e.g. with enter) the input

Comment: @MoritzRingler browser? not working in chrome for me.

Comment: @MoritzRingler Please only type `1` in the input, don't click on the button, in my browser, it only shows `OK` near the input, and don't scroll into `div.here`

Comment: I am I am. Just typing in 1. Does not work with other input or subsequent 1s. I am using Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: Tested in Chromium, does not work, as you said

Comment: Apparently, the `smooth` behavior is a [problem in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885401/scrollintoview-is-not-working-in-chrome-version-81-behaviour-smooth-is-not-hap). If you remove it, you see it doing something. I think it jumps to the top margin

Comment: @MoritzRingler Unexpectedly this is a browser issue. Thank you for explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

So, seems to be an issue with Chrome. Apparently, the `nextTick()` hits too early. I think there is an event from `keyup` which stops Chrome from scrolling the `<input>` out of view. That is why the button works, but not the text input.

It works if you put it into a `setTimeout()`:

```
watch(matchAddress, async (val) => {
  if (val) {
    setTimeout(() => scrollToView());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. This is vanilla JS though. In Vue you just need to change the `onkeyup(event)` to `@keyup($event)`. And the `window.scrollTo` might need to change to `outerComponent.scrollTo`. Just type "1" into the input.

```js
function checkValue(event) {
  const inputVal = event.currentTarget.value
  const hereDiv = document.querySelector('.here')
  if (inputVal === '1') {
    
    // In Vue you might have to change "window" to the to your outer component ref.
    window.scrollTo({ 
      top: hereDiv.offsetTop,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.here {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkValue(event)">
<div class="here">
```

Comment: actually, I use `v-model` to bind a child component to use search and scroll there. That child component contains a list to search. For this example, I want to clarify why `scrollToView ` doesn't work in `watch`.